# This is to inform that... vs This is to inform you that

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

This second sentence looks fine to me. In the first sentence (This is to inform that...) I believe a pronoun is missing. But I need an expert opinion on this. Is the first sentence grammatically wrong?

Comment: For most contexts (definitely including yours) ***to inform*** is a ***transitive*** verb. That means you need to specify an ***object*** (the person being informed, ***you*** in your context). You don't need an "expert" to tell you that this verb is normally transitive - that's one of the key items of information given in *any* dictionary definition.

Comment: I agree with you. The word 'inform' requires an indirect object (you). So, the first sentence needs correction.

Comment: Offhand, the only *intransitive* usage I can think of is where the unstated "object" is ***the authorities, military, police*** (as in "a police informer" = rat / spy / nark).